# Harness that connects power inverter and motors 2013 Ford C-MAX hybrid

Tags: ford, parts

I have the power inverter and the two motors from the 2013 Ford C-Max hybrid.  I use them for my research.

I need the harness to connect the inverter and the two motors.  I went to a Ford dealer said I want to buy the harness.  I told them I can point out where exactly it is located under hood.  But they ask me what is the part number.  I think if I can point out where it is exactly, shouldn't they tell me the part number?

Anyone knows what the part number is for the three-phase harness? Or anyone knows any method I can use to find the part number for the harness?

I'll deeply appreciate your help.

Comment: I would go to a different Ford dealership. They have the pictures which come up on the screen. You should be able to point out the portion you need, as you've said. I would not, however, tell them what you need it for. Just tell them you need the harness but don't have the part number.

Answer (score 1):

Paulster2 is correct. They can look up the part number.  They may need to ask you some questions to figure out which harness you're after which may involve looking at some diagrams.  When dealing with parts departments I find taking a box of doughnuts works wonders.  You might be able to find it yourself by browsing/searching [fordparts.com](http://www.fordparts.com/Commerce/CatalogResults.aspx?y=2013&m=Ford&mo=C-Max&initSearch=1&keyword=harness#Search) (Official Ford Parts site)